# Why is this not running?

Tags: python

The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import Quandl
df= Quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
print (df.head())
```

Error received:

```
IDLE internal error in runcode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 236, in asyncqueue
AttributeError: 'MyRPCClient' object has no attribute 'sockthread'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a runtime error, close all python processes, restart (if you're using it) IDLE and it should work.